# Is possible to retrieve age and gender from video using Azure Media Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, artificial-intelligence, face-api

I am a newbie in using [Azure Media Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/). Last day I set up a project ( in MVC C#) with Azure Media Services. I already set up a media service account in Azure.Everything works fine and I got an output file in JSON format. But that contains the per person details with various emotion values.

Please see my job file below:

```
  {
  "version": "1.0",
  "options": {
    "aggregateEmotionWindowMs": "987",
    "mode": "PerFaceEmotion",
    "aggregateEmotionIntervalMs": "342"
  }
}
```

Is there any option to get Age and Gender of peoples in video. I already saw the documentation about the Face API but that only manipulate with the image files not with videos.

Comment: Did you try with the Azure Media services Video Indexer?